# Can't find exact value of $x = \frac{\pi}{\cot^{-1}(\frac{4\pi}{x})}$

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

I can't find the exact value of x for the equation $x = \frac{\pi}{\cot^{-1}(\frac{4\pi}{x})}$. I tried typing it into wolfram alpha and it only gave me a decimal approximation, approximately equal to 6.543697264. If you click this link https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rcf54bxjsz, then when t equals the number in the photo then the yellow line exactly matches the dotted black line, which is the formula for finding a circles radius if you only know its area.
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PROPP.png)

Comment: The solutions of most equations, particular those mixing both algebraic and transcendental functions, don't have so called closed forms. That is, they cannot be written in terms of the elementary functions. This is likely to be one such.

Comment: Oooh, so the x here is the t in the link. As I understand, t is the number of sides of the regular polygon. So the equation here is solving for the number of sides where the side of the polygon will be equal to the radius of the circle.

Matlab gives me 6.54369 as well. This is probably as trancendental number. On the other hand, I understand a hexagon is as close as we will get to that.

Comment: You just need to solve $y\tan(y)=\frac14,x=\frac\pi y$ or $e^{-w}\frac{w-\frac12}{w+\frac12}=1,x=-\frac{2\pi}{i w}$. This [arxiv article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.3999.pdf) gives solutions for similar equations to the last equation. However, trying the series expansion from it does not work. Maybe this info will be useful to others interested

Comment: At the time I posted this, I thought the answer would be useful to me but I realize now that it's the wrong equation. It's a difficult challenge though so I'm gonna keep it up so others can improve their algebra/problem-solving skills.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "exact solution"?

A lot of numbers are much easier to express as the equations they solve than a closed form of given functions or algebraic expressions.

Maybe there does not exist a closed form expression. In fact it is often so much easier to express numbers as equations it can often be a means of quite efficient data compression.

For example $x^2+y^2 = 1$ is fulfilled by all numbers on the unit circle. How would you capture that solution set in any easier or more compact way?

Sometimes the right thing to do is not to find a solution set for an equation but rather the best equation which matches the solution set.